# MySQL Error with SELECT * FROM (SELECT *...)

Tags: mysql, sql, union, multiple-tables

My trainee have create a SQL request (using MySQL) like :

```
SELECT xxx.*
FROM reservation r, 
     user u,
     (
          SELECT * FROM  MyTable_sauv_01
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM  MyTable_sauv_02
     ) AS xxx
WHERE r.id_user = u.id
AND   r.id = xxx.id
```

When he wants to execute this request : mysql error (not executed).

If he puts the "tables" after its xxx "reformatted table", the request is executed :

```
SELECT xxx.*
FROM 
     (
          SELECT * FROM  MyTable_sauv_01
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM  MyTable_sauv_02
     ) AS xxx,
     reservation r, 
     user u
WHERE r.id_user = u.id
AND   r.id = xxx.id
```

I know that this request is not well implemented (he must use JOIN to link tables and i got to explain to him that its too baaaad) but i ask me why MySQL execute the request only when other tables are after the (SELECT * FROM ... UNION SELECT * FROM ...) ?

Thanks you for your response :)

Comment: please read up on the modern ANSI join syntax, the method you're using here is old and very difficult to read.

Comment: Please post the output off EXPLAIN off both qeuries.

Comment: I've attempted to recreate this error and failed (http://rextester.com/BDMBO38348). There must be something else going on here.

Comment: Ideas as to the something else: (1) typos in actual code which aren't present in the question here, (2) you're running the code in an environment which attempts to check the syntax before sending to the database engine, but it get's it wrong, (3) some oddities in your data / data types which make it a special case, (4) there is a bug in the version of MySQL you are running, (5) something else I can't think of. Option (4) seems unlikely. Take these by turn (not necessarily in order), and update your question with further details ... or add your own answer if you've found an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove As keyword and Try,

```
SELECT xxx.*
FROM 
     (
          SELECT * FROM  MyTable_sauv_01
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM  MyTable_sauv_02
     ) xxx,
     reservation r, 
     user u
WHERE r.id_user = u.id
AND   r.id = xxx.id
```

Comment: Always those "try" answers, i can tell you already that removing a AS keyword wont help